# Converting dryer from 3 to 4 prong cord but it doesn't have a grounding screw / wire

Tags: electrical, dryer

[image]

I'm trying to convert a recently purchased dryer from a three prong cord to a four prong cord to match my outlet. However, it doesn't have a green screw for the ground line. Where do I connect the green cord?

Comment: Make/model # of the dryer?

Comment: dclr333et1ww . It's a GE electric dryer

Comment: Wow - that's an ancient beast.  Are you certain that your 4-prong is providing the correct voltages and phases the dryer expects?

Comment: screw or no screw, provisioned or not, at the end of the day, ground should be connected to the metal body of the appliance. use a continuity tester to very that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### I'd try the screw above N for ground

It looks like the hex-slot screw going into the top center of the metal plate above the terminal block is your ground screw, so I'd land the cord ground there.  It doesn't need to be connected to a wire within the dryer, either: the cord ground simply needs to ground the dryer's chassis/frame to provide protection from electric shock.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't appear to be connected to anything though http://imgur.com/a/Nz1NwLb

Comment: @Michael That's probably the intended ground then. The screw is directly connected to that piece of metal that it is screwed into, which is connected to the body of the dryer.

Answer (score 0):

Green screw for the neutral? The neutral is shown as the middle of the 3 terminals and labelled as such.

There should be a grounding point in the area somewhere for the green or green/yellow cable.

Comment: My bad, I meant ground. Nothing around there is green or yellow, however

Answer (score -5):

Ground to n .. L1 l2 both 120v nuetral= ground

Comment: No, unfortunately this is a common misconception, and this advice is dangerous.  Neutral is not the same as ground, even though they are connected in the panel.  Neutral normally carries current, whereas ground should not, and this is important for safety reasons.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Aside from the factual problems in your answer, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.